# multiple graphs in one plot Tikz

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, tikz-arrows, arrows, plot

I would like to patch different graphs in one. Moreover, the two in the right are also linked by two dotted lines. How can I do it? Here the final result:

[image]

Here the codes of the single figures that I would like to put in the same figure with Tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem,multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=6, 
    xlabel={\large $q$}, 
    xlabel style={below right}, 
    ylabel={\large $E_k(q)$}, 
    ylabel style={above},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    xtick={0.01, 4},
    xticklabels = {$0$, $2k_F$},
    ]
  \addplot[very thick, samples=300, domain=0:6, name path=A] {-0.5 * x^2 + 2*x}; 
  \addplot[very thick, samples=300, domain=0:8, name path=B] {2*x- 8}; 
  \addplot[very thick,  samples=300, domain=3:7, name path=C] {6}; 
  \addplot[very thick, samples=300, domain=0:6, name path=D] {2*x};
  \addplot[gray] fill between[of=D and A, soft clip={domain=0:4}];
  \addplot[gray] fill between[of= C and B, soft clip={domain=3.95:8}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%SECOND PLOT
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
            \fill[gray!50] (-1,1) to[out=-60,in=180] (0,0) to[out=0,in=-120] (1,1) --cycle;
            \draw[-stealth] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below right]{$k$};
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above right]{$E$};
            \draw
                (-1,1) -- (1,1)
                (-1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) 
                (1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) ;
            \draw (-1.7,2) to[out=-45,in=120] (-1,1) to[out=-60,in=180] (0,0) to[out=0,in=-120] (1,1) to[out=60,in=-135] (1.7,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

%THIRD PLOT
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=6, 
    xlabel={\large $q$}, 
    xlabel style={below right}, 
    ylabel={\large $E_k(q)$}, 
    ylabel style={above},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    xtick={0.01, 4},
    xticklabels = {$0$, $2k_F$},
    ]
  
  \addplot[very thick, samples=300, domain=0:6, name path=A] {0}; 
  
  \addplot[very thick, samples=300, domain=0:8, name path=B] {2*x- 8}; 
  q
  \addplot[very thick,  samples=300, domain=3:7, name path=C] {6}; 
  
  \addplot[very thick, samples=300, domain=0:6, name path=D] {2*x};
  
  \addplot[gray] fill between[of=D and A, soft clip={domain=0:4}];
  
  \addplot[gray] fill between[of= C and B, soft clip={domain=3.95:8}];
  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%FOURTH PLOT
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[very thick, circle, draw, radius = 5cm] at (0,0){};
    \draw [-stealth,very thick](-1,0) -- (0,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

PS. how can I add the shaded area?

Comment: Could you possibly make your code compilable by adding an appropriate `documentclass` and all the required packages and libraries, as well as custom definitions (e.g. option `axline` is not defined by default).

Comment: You can try using `scopes` for the segments of code you want on top of each other within one `tikzpicture` enviroment. Then you could also define the coordinates for the dotted arrows.

Comment: Now it should work, sorry if I've been too sloppy ://

Comment: I'm trying to use "scope", but I've never seen it before. can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `scope`s and `coordinates` to get you started:

**EDIT:** Added some more of the arrows using `decorations` based on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349967/118712 .

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem,multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,arrows,arrows.meta,intersections,decorations.markings,bending}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \begin{scope}
            \draw[thick,<->,>=stealth] (7,0) node[anchor=north west] {$q$} -- (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0} -- (0,7) node[anchor=south] {$E_k (q)$};
            \fill[left color=white,right color=gray!90,draw,thick] (0.01,0) -- ++(2,6) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(-2,-6) node[anchor=north]{$2k_f$} .. controls (3,2) and (1,1.5) .. cycle;
            \coordinate (A) at (5,1);
            \coordinate (C) at (-0.5,1);
        \end{scope}
    
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm,xshift=3cm]
            \fill[gray!50] (-1,1) to[out=-60,in=180] (0,0) to[out=0,in=-120] (1,1) --cycle;
            \draw[-stealth,thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$k$};
            \draw[-stealth,thick] (0,0) -- (0,3) node[anchor=south west]{$E$};
            \coordinate (B) at (1,2);
            \draw[name path=P](-1,1) -- ++(2,0);        
            \draw(-1,2pt) -- ++(0,-4pt) 
            (1,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) ;
            \draw[decoration={markings,%
                mark=at position 0.14 with {\coordinate (S);},
                mark=at position 0.19 with {\coordinate (R);},
                mark=at position 0.28 with {\coordinate (P); \fill[black] circle [radius=2pt];},
                mark=at position 0.72 with {\coordinate (Q); \fill[black] circle [radius=2pt];},
            },
                postaction=decorate
            ] (-1.7,2) to[out=-45,in=120] (-1,1)  to[out=-60,in=180] (0,0)  to[out=0,in=-120] (1,1)  to[out=60,in=-135] (1.7,2);
            \draw[thick,->,>=stealth] (Q) -- (R);
            \draw[thick,->,>=stealth,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\coordinate (X);}},postaction=decorate] (P) to[out=200,in=200] (S);
        \end{scope}
        
        \draw[dashed,->,>=stealth,ultra thick,shorten >=.2cm] (C) -- ++(-1,0) |-  (X);
        \draw[dashed,->,>=stealth,ultra thick] (A) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-2) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also managed to put the other all in the same figure :-)